# PayPal Advanced Credit Card Processing Not Eligible on Live

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the paypal hosted fields working on my sandbox business accounts. When trying to go live, it does not allow me to make an app that supports advanced debit card processing. In the sandbox they give you the option of making a platform app, but this option is not available to me in the live environment. It seems that only the platform apps have the "advanced debit card and credit card processing" feature in them.

Of course I am using a paypal business account to make these apps, so how do I get the ability to make a platform app for a live environment? I need to do hosted field credit card processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guide for integrating Advanced, the ["Next Steps" section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/#link-nextsteps) has a link to [complete production onboarding](https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/entry/product/ppcp) with a live account. This is required.